# Print current number of elements of queue in each second in thread safe manner

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to print current number of elements of data queue in each second in multithreaded program like this:

```
queue<int> products;
void print(ostream& s)
{
    cout << s.rdbuf();
    cout.flush();
    s.clear();
}
void printQueue()
{
    while(true)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        print(stringstream() << "Number of prouducts: " << products.size() << "\n");
    }
}

void producer(int i)
{ //adds data into queue in thread safe manner
}
void consumer(int i)
{/*removes data from queue in thread safe manner*/}

int main()
{
  vector<thread> thrds;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        thrds.push_back(thread(producer, i));

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        thrds.push_back(thread(consumer, i));

     thrds.push_back(thread(printQueue));

    for(auto& t : thrds)
        t.join();
}
return 0;
}
```

printQueue - is this function thread safe?

Answer (score 2):

There are two resources accessed by multiple threads:

- `std::cout`
- `products`

Typical implementations of `std::cout` are relatively resistent to being accessed by multiple threads, though they don't guarantee that output isn't e.g. interleaved. Still, formally there is no synchronization, so your writes are not threadsafe.

Concerning `products`, your accesses there are not protected by any mutex either, which also makes these accesses non-threadsafe. It doesn't matter that in some places you only read the size. Not that this read access could break anything, but the results (i.e. when you see changes and what you see) are undefined still.

Summary: Use a mutex to protect shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

Being `printQueue` thread-safe or not depeneds on the `std::queue` contract. For every container thread-specific behaviour of the method they expose would fall into one of following major categories:

- thread synchronized
- thread safe
- thread unsafe (can generate a race)

The 3rd one means that this call can never be used in unprotected environment - meaning, there can be no other calls to any other methods of the container while this call is happening. The difference between 1 and 2 is that for the first option you are guaranteed to read new value after it was modified in another thread (with a reasonable delay). Thread safe does not give you this guarantee, but still states that calling this method will not exposure your program to data race and you are guaranteed to read either old value or new value, but there is no undefined behavior.

For a standard container as `std::queue`, all their const methods are thread safe, while non-const methods are thread-unsafe. Since you will be calling thread unsafe push, you need to protect your access with an external synchronization.

Comment: Can you give a pointer indicating that const access is thread-safe? I commented an earlies (now deleted) answer where a similar claim was made, and determining the size of a `deque` might require jumping through a few pointers, so any changes in between might cause a race there.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I believe I made myself clear above. size() of the deque is thread safe on itself, meaning, you can call it from multiple threads at the same time. Calling it at the same time with unsafe function is a data race, and I clearly stated so: *meaning, there can be no other calls to any other methods of the container while this call is happening*

Comment: So all you have to do to use size() safely is ensure that no other threads are calling unsafe methods at the same time.  Do you have any suggestions about how to achieve this magic?  Without such protection the "thread-safeness' of the size method is not worth much.

Comment: Actually no, you didn't make yourself clear: "old or new value" implies change from some other thread, which is exactly not what you want!

Comment: @Ulrich, why? There might be a change from the other thread, done through another thread-safe function - and this might be read as either new or old.

Comment: @DaleWilson, my first part was generic. It didn't apply to a particular container or particular method of it, hence 'For every container ... of the methods they expose...'. There is no mentioning of size() or queue(). There are plenty of objects which provide thread safe, but not thread synchronized interfaces.

Comment: @DaleWilson, and as for the `size()` itself, the thread safety of it (together with other const-qualified function of `queue`) worth a ton. For example, you can crate an object before you spawn any threads, share a const reference to it with multiple threads and sleep safely knowing that you need no extra synchronization around it.

Comment: There are no safe ways to change a `queue` from different threads without any additional synchronization. Now, when you say that you can use the `const` functions to read things and that you will get the old or new value, that's contradicting, because you can't safely change any value! Note that retrieving the size doesn't mean it's just a simple access to an integer member, it could also calculate `end - begin`, which will break when either of them changes in the middle. That's also the reason I asked for any indication that it's thread-safe, I simply don't believe that's guaranteed.